Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS Slow Performance: Frequent Freezes in VS Code, Slack, Chrome, and Firefox
I recently upgraded my laptop to Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) from Ubuntu 20.x, and I have been experiencing significant performance issues since the upgrade. The system becomes very slow, especially when using applications like Slack, VS Code, Chrome, and Firefox. At times, the entire system freezes, and I have to wait for it to respond.
Here's my current system information:

Ubuntu version: 22.04.4 LTS
I previously used Ubuntu 20.x, and it performed much better with no noticeable slowdowns.

Problems I'm facing:

Slack, VS Code, Chrome, and Firefox become unresponsive frequently.
General system lag in basic operations like switching windows and opening files.
The system occasionally freezes and stops responding for several seconds or more.

I tried the usual troubleshooting methods like restarting the system, checking for updates, and reducing background applications, but the performance remains sluggish. My laptop has sufficient RAM and processing power, and these issues did not occur in the previous version.
Has anyone else faced similar issues with Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS? Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!
